# Display BLOB image from db using JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I tried to display my images using JSON but I got

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

as an error. I tried many things, many ways to solve it, but I failed. I can display text (from a table that has not images (BLOB), I tested it ), but when I try with a table which contains images I got the error.

Here is my code:

PHP - for getting images:

```html
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
//header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');
$obj = json_decode($_GET["x"], false);

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "abu", "aburefko159753", "btt");
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM " . $obj->table . " LIMIT " . $obj->limit);
$output = array();
$output = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

HTML and JS code for display the images:

```js
<script>
        var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp;
        obj = { "table":"bestPlaces", "limit":4 };
        dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                console.log(this.responseText);
                var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = myObj[0].ID;
                console.log(myObj[0].ID);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "getPlaces.php?x=" + dbParam, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    </script>
```

```html
  <p id="test"></p>
  <p id="test2"></p>
```

the same code works fine when I use another table which has not images and the output would be :

```
[{"ID":"1","name":"test bez session","content":"abu test test"},
 {"ID":"2","name":"test bez session","content":"abu test test"},
 {"ID":"3","name":"test bez session","content":"test test 2"},
 {"ID":"4","name":"test bez session","content":"abu juhu test"}
]
```

1

But it crash when I use table with images. Any help?

Comment: It crashes with WHAT ERROR

Comment: @RiggsFolly I put the error message in the question...Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: I dont know the answer, but I would guess that JSON is too big when it contains one or more images

Comment: So what you recommended me to use instead of json? I'm trying to make carousel (slideshow) using some images from my db..you may know a better way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Does `console.log(this.responseText);` show the full JSON output?

My guess is that you're having trouble with json_encode or JSON.parse on the binary data.  Try encoding it in base64 using:

```
$output['imageCol'] = base64_encode($output['imageCol']);
echo json_encode($output);
```

where `imageCol` is the name of the BLOB column and then in JS:

```
var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
myObj.imageCol = atob(myObj.imageCol);
```

Comment: console.log(this.responseText) works fine when I use table without image, but when it is with image it output nothing.

I tried to use base64_endoce but it show error that img (blob column in the table) is undefined (PHP error).

Then I tried to use only the code you write for JS, but it still show the previous error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input'

Answer (score 0):

You have used

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "getPlaces.php?x=" + dbParam, true);
```

it means you are trying to get image data using *`get`* method which has data limitations / restrictions.
So, it is advised to use **`POST`** method instead **`GET`**.

Hope it works...